# MoST called in queries in postgresql in last 30 minutes

Tags: postgresql

IN pg_stat_statements there is column named 'calls' which hold the value of total no of times query called , but it shows the data of all time , on the other hand i want only the most called queries in last 30 minutes .

Answer (score 0):

Look at `pg_stat_statements.calls` before and after the 30 minutes and calculate the difference.

Comment: is there any script to show these changes b'coz it is not posiible manually .There is a partiular server and on this server lots of users are active . So the size of this is very big .

Answer (score -1):

check pgsentinel extension that will act as oracleash and u can query history tables